# Spring 2.6.3 how to return id in response

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Im making a api with spring, in which I return an array of objects, each of them contains name and an array. The problem is that it doesn't return the Id of each object which I store in jpa repository. The question is how do I turn Id visible in response

```
@Column
private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
private String QuestionName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening,

Some more information about how you are structuring your project should be in order.
However, I am going to assume your code snippet is from a class using the @`Entity` annotation.

If so, you require a Class noted with `@RestController`, where a `@PostMapping` function would be defined where you would receive your information from the client (Possibly in a JSON format, which can be directly converted into a Map by the application). By using a function with a return format of `ResponseEntity`, you can return HTTP messages to the client. In this return statement, you may return whatever you please, meaning you may return a JSON back to the client in question.

Personally, I recommend creating a QuestionDTO class (Data Transfer Object), in order to not send the Object with all Server-Side information to the client-side, easing creation of client-side code too!

I know this was a lot to take in, I leave some sources down here:

[Response Entities and how they work](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity)

[Building REST applications with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)

I hope this was of use, hit me up if you need further assistance,

Have a good one!

Comment: I managed to make it work, just above the getter I added @JsonProperty(value="id") and it works like a charm. Still, your answer is by far the most informative. Thanks a lot

Comment: Additional Information on why not to combine JPA with and REST in a single object:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-4684

Answer (score 0):

Add getter and setter methods for id field and then try.